# Azure Application Gateway - This site cant be reached

Tags: azure

> > I have created an appication gatweay in Azure for HTTPS I uploaded the .pfx certificate WAF is enabled I created an App Service
>
> Web Apps I created 3 Web Apps one which will be used for Devtest
>   website, One for PreProd and one for Live I then created 3 back end
>   pools with the FQDN of each of the above webapps
>
> 3 Listeners were created for each environment as follows
>   devtestlistner which points to DevTest.mydoamin.com prepodListerner
>   which points to preprod.mydomain.co liveListerner which points to
>   live.mydomain.com
>
> Routing Rules added devRule which points to devtestListener
>   preprodRule which points to PreProdListener LiveRule which point to
>   LiveListener
>
> The DNS name of the appgateway was entered into my domains DNS to
>   point to the AppGateway
>
> However when i navigate to any of the webiste i get  This site can’t
>   be reached 58e32322e-2dd8-4ce3-baa8-0990e837878.cloudapp.net took too
>   long to respond ???
>
> When I use the Azure dns above I still get this error?
>
> Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you access the `https://DevTest.mydomain.com` successfully?

Comment: i can now reach the webapps via the domains, eg if i type in https://devtest.mydomain.com it does now go to the dev.azurewebsites.net, however if I use the IP or the DNS label of the appgateway it still times out?

Comment: If so, i suppose you have cname devtest in your custom domain point to dev web app site, and the dev.azurewebsites.net is set the application gateway backend pool. right?

Comment: the cname for devtest,mydomain.com points to the dns of the appgateway, do i need to do anything else to configure. There will in total be 3 urls pointing to 3 web apps. devtest.mydomain.com, staging.mydomain,com and  prod.mydomain.com

Comment: nobody knows the answer to this??